# While loop to insert values into database using radio button for many user

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach, while-loop

This function is to insert values into the database. at first, it will list down all the students in class '$class'. the interface is like below:

//I can't post an image since i don't have much reputations. But, the interface is it will list down all students with column "NO", "Birth No", "Student Name", "Attendance". In column attendance, it will display 3 radio buttons which is, PT, AT, MC. Out of the table there is a submit button.

The problem is, when I click submit button after I clicked on the radio button for both students, there is nothing that inserted in the database.

```
$id = 1;
$getdata = mysql_query("select * from student where class = '$class' order by name ")     or die(mysql_query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata))
    {
        if(isset($_POST['a'.$id])) 
        {
            $status = $_POST['a'.$id];      

            if(!empty($status))
            {
                if($status == "present")
                {
                    $attend = 1;
                }
                else if($status == "absent")
                {
                    $attend = 0;
                }
                else if($status == "mc")
                {
                    $attend = 1;
                }

                $query = "INSERT INTO attendance VALUES ('$birth_no','$date','$status','$attend')";
                if($query_run = mysql_query($query))
                {
                    echo 'Insert attendance done';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo'Attendance not inserted.';
                }                   

            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Please enter all fields';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //FORM CODE HERE
            ?>
            <form action="addattend.php" method = "POST">
            <?php

                $birth_no= $row['birth_no'];
                $name = $row['name'];

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><center><?php echo $id ?></center></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $date ?></center></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $birth_no ?></center></td>
                        <td><center><?php echo $name ?></center></td>
                        <?php
                    echo'<td>
                            <input type="radio" name="a'.$id.'" value="present">PT
                            <input type="radio" name="a'.$id.'" value="absent">AT
                            <input type="radio" name="a'.$id.'" value="mc">MC
                        </td>
                    </tr> ';
        }
        $id++;      
    }

            ?>

            </table>
            <center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
            </form>
            <?php
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem? I try solved this problem for a week. But nothing came out. Really appreciate your kindness. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need to use the foreach loop at all since the status variable will have exactly one value so technically there is nothing to iterate through.

Comment: also, can you post what your attendance table looks like since your insert query statement might not be correct?

Comment: table name: attendance, column:birth_no(varchar20),date(date),status(varchar20),attend(varchar5)

Comment: Are you getting any error message with the updated code ?

Comment: There's no error message. It goes back to the the first state before submit button clicked.

Comment: so you need one form for each student. Is that correct ?

Comment: what I want is, 1 form for all students. Means that, when I click submit button, all values will be inserted to all students.

Comment: then you should take your form code out of the while loop.

Comment: look at the answer that I added. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get it - you are looping an array called `$_POST['a'.$id.'']`, but if I look at your form, there is no such array created in your inputs. You are using radio buttons like `<input type="radio" name="a'.$id.'" value="mc">MC`, which will create a `$_POST['a1']` with "mc" as the value if its active. But `$_POST['a1']` is NOT an array, it just contains this single value!

So you should kick out the foreach-loop and work mit `$_POST['a'.$id]` as your `$status`. In other works, make a

```
$status = $_POST['a'.$id] // by the way you do not need .'' in the end of the key
```

instead of your foreach-loop.

Additionally, it seems like your script is **not secure**. You are not using csrf-, xss-, and sql-injection-protection. You really really need to inform yourself about security in php applications (csrf, xss, sql-injections). This is extremly important!

Comment: I already edit my code like what you asked me to do. But, it is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps. I made some changes to the form display/processing logic based on various comments above. I didn't get a chance to test this so there might be small formatting errors here and there. Also, it should be possible to simplify this code further.

```
$getdata = mysql_query("select * from student where 
         class = '$class' order by name ")     or die(mysql_query);

// form processing logic goes here
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $id = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
        if(isset($_POST['a'.$id])) {
            $status = $_POST['a'.$id];      
            if(!empty($status)){
                if(($status == "present" || $status == "mc")){
                    $attend = 1;
                }
                else if($status == "absent"){
                    $attend = 0;
                }
                $query = "INSERT INTO attendance(birth_no, date, status, attend) 
                VALUES ('$birth_no','$date','$status','$attend')";
                if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
                    echo 'Insert attendance done';
                }
                else{
                    echo'Attendance not inserted.';
                }                   
            }
            else{
                echo 'Please enter all fields';
            }
        }
        $id ++;
    } // end while
} // end if
// show the form here
else {
?>   
    <form action="addattend.php" method = "POST">
    <table>
<?php
    $id = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata)){
        $birth_no= $row['birth_no'];
        $name = $row['name'];
?>
        <tr>
            <td><center><?php echo $id ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $date ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $birth_no ?></center></td>
            <td><center><?php echo $name ?></center></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="a<?php echo $id; ?>" value="present">PT
                <input type="radio" name="a<?php echo $id; ?>" value="absent">AT
                <input type="radio" name="a<?php echo $id; ?>" value="mc">MC
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php
        $id ++;
    } // end while
?>
    </table>
    <center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></center>
    </form> <!-- end the form here -->
<?php    
} // end else
?>
```

Comment: There's still nothing happens when I edit the code that you gave me. :(

Comment: you might need to make more changes to this code based on any error message that you might be getting.